# Installing Framework 7 CLI

Tags: npm, html-framework-7

I'm trying to download Framework7 CLI - I'm also not a developer that develops and opens programs through command lines

I know the install is explained fairly decent, but when it says to enter

$ npm install framework7

Where do I enter that command? I used to be able to download the files directly, but now when I do the functionality isn't there. I also watched this video on youtube but it didn't help

https://youtu.be/65hfVB49PZU

Thank you in advance...

I've asked questions on the net and nobody has gotten back to me.

$ npm install framework7

There are none I haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the CLI to a terminal or you can directly download the necessary files and add it to your project via this link: https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7/releases/

Just click on the Source code(zip) under the v4.4.3 release. Then move the bundle.js and bundle.css files to your project file.

In your app.html file, define the paths like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/framework7.bundle.min.css">
<script src="path/to/framework7.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

You can also look at the kitchen-sink folder, it's very helpful. Make sure you're running the folders on a server or localhost.